# Automated tests for multiclass classification ML

Tags: machine-learning, automated-tests, artificial-intelligence, multiclass-classification

Problem statement:
There are around 100 million items that needs to be classified into "codes" (there are in total around 10K codes). Each item can have one unique code only. We've written an ML model that maps items to codes. I'm looking for an automated way to determine the precision metrics with minimal manual effort. What's the best way to go about? Ideally I'm looking for a completely automated mechanism after a point in time.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the problem you're facing?

Comment: We use stratified sampling methodology to figure out precision metrics. However, this always involves a manual effort as the QA takes a sample of X items and manually classifies them, and then determines the precision by the ratio (true positive/X). However, because of manual nature of the QA methodology, we do it once every 3 months only (it takes around 3 business days to figure out the precision based on the stratified sampling methodology). I'm looking for a cheaper way for calculation of precision, ideally zero manual effort (if possible).

Comment: So you're trying to work around the need of ground truth labels for [some of] your data, or is the problem the process around the (labeled data, model) pair?

Comment: I'm open for alternate precision calculation methodologies as well (I'm an ML beginner and looking for learning from experts on this forum). The bottleneck in the 3 business day period is labelling the sampled data to correct value which takes 99% of time.

Comment: I cannot really help you on this, from my (academic) perspective, you either do have the labels or you don't. And if you want to calculate precision (or any other supervised metric), you need them. However (1) I do not think it's a programming question appropriate for SO and (2) I would invest time as needed to get enough many labels which you can reuse, effectively forming a test set to report on.